# Delete Files that are more than than 10 days old using Linq

Tags: linq

i'm using the code below to delete the files that are more than 10 days old. Is there a simpler/smarter way of doing this?

```
string source_path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["source_path"];
            string filename= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filename"];

            var fileQuery= from file in Directory.GetFiles(source_path,filename,SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                           where File.GetCreationTime(file)<System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10)
                           select file;

            foreach(var f in fileQuery)
            {
                File.Delete(f);
            }
```

Answer (score 6):

Well there are two things I'd change:

- Determine the cut-off `DateTime` *once*, rather than re-evaluating `DateTime.Now` repeatedly
- I wouldn't use a query expression when you've just got a `where` clause:

So I'd rewrite the query part as:

```
var cutoff = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
var query = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, filename, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                     .Where(f => File.GetCreationTime(f) < cutoff);
```

Another alternative would be to use `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo`:

```
var cutoff = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
var path = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
var query = path.GetFiles(filename, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .Where(fi => fi.CreationTime < cutoff);
```

(In .NET 4 you might also want to use `EnumerateFiles` instead.)

Comment: Definitely would recommend `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` if you're using .NET 4 - if there are a lot of files, it can make a noticeable difference.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to do a LINQ "one-liner" to perform this process:

```
Directory.GetFiles(source_path,filename,SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
.Where(f => File.GetCreationTime(file) < System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10))
.All(f => {File.Delete(f); return true;);
```

Don't forget to wrap the code in a try catch.

Comment: Using `Enumerable.All` this way is not something I'd ever recommend.  Purposefully writing side effects into a query operator is fairly ugly, IMO.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Fair enough. I was going to write a caveat about how it is **possible** but not **recommended**, but I ended up not doing that. I guess I deserve the downvote :).